# Moment generating function for Gamma

Tags: probability

Edit:I originally posted the completely wrong MGF of the equation (I was looking at a completely different question and it won't let me make multiple posts!, so:)

so I am solving a question which obtains the MGF of $Z_n$ which I calculated to be$$M_x(Z) = [\frac{L}{L-T}]^2$$

I did this and defined T < L.

Would I be right in thinking that this leads to a Gamma distribution? My working looks like it's heading there but this isn't a common distribution that my class discusses with these questions so I may be wrong. If anyone could point me into the right direction that would be fantastic.

Comment: This is just a constant random variable. See also [Degenerate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: Please don't deface the post after having received answers.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{3t}$ is not the MGF of a normal distribution. It is the MGF of of the constant $Z=3$: $Ee^{tZ}=e^{3t}$ when $Z=3$.

MGF of a (symmetric) normal distribution is of the  form $e^{ct^{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, in this case you can just say $Z=3$ without showing any work since it is so simple. @Taylor